# Forward HTTPS Request to different address

Tags: haproxy

I want to forward requests hitting - https://a.com/a/a1 to https://b.com/a1. (Want the /a uri stripped and the remaining forwarded to backend)
I have a haproxy setup for the a.com domain and i tried putting this config in haproxy:

```
acl a_redirect path_beg /a
  use_backend be-a if a_redirect

backend be-a
   reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)a[/]?(.*)     \1\2
   server a  b.com:443 ssl verify none
```

But i dont see the forward happening. Can any of you correct my configuration?

Comment: Thank you for formatting. I was about to do that,but got busy reading the doc on formatting.